# Excel Function for Finding Product Numbers in different files and then

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, lookup, matching

I have two excel documents(X and Y), both contain product numbers in column A, but file X does not have the image that goes with the product number.  File Y has this but it needs to be put into file X in column B.  However file Y has missing product numbers so sorting will not work. File X contains over 58,000 product numbers so it would take quite some time to do this manually.

What I believe I need to do is write a function that takes product number 113 from file X and finds the product number, if available, in file Y. Then, if found, return cell B from file Y(which has the filename of the image to use) to cell B of the the original, in file X, product number's row.

Here is an illustration of what I am trying to accomplish. [Sample Here](http://craigcarrolldesign.com/example.jpg)

Comment: Can you copy the img path data to a new sheet in the first and just use `vlookup`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ON B2 cell in X excel document put the below formula:

This is considering Format of Column A in X and Y files are same
=VLOOKUP(A2,[Y.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,0)

and drag this formula till the row in column B where you have product data in X

and Looking at your data, Consider format of Column A in X is in General and format in Column A in Y is in Text. Use the below formula

=VLOOKUP(A27&"",[Y.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,0)

Comment: This works! But only on my test files. When I paste into B2 of my actual excel file I get #N/A. Any suggestions? Everything appears to be the same... [Sample Here](http://craigcarrolldesign.com/example2.png)

Comment: @CraigCarroll the format of Column A in X and Y are different. It seems Column A in X is in General Format and column A in Y is in Text format. Keep Same format for Column A in Both the excel document

Comment: I have updated the formula, looking at your data: use this =VLOOKUP(A27&"",[Y.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,0) and let me know if this works